# If I update angularjs, do I need to rewrite protractor tests?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor, angularjs-1.6

I have a local webapp written in AngularJS v1.5.8 and thinking about starting testing with protractor. If I update Angular in the future, is there a chance I'll have to rewrite protractor tests because of version issues between the two?

I know that I already have to worry about version dependencies between protractor and nodejs, but if there's a chance I have to rewrite protractor tests, I may as well just start with Selenium, right?

Comment: What makes you think you won't have to ever rewrite Selenium tests?

Comment: I mean if I change element positions and stuff the Selenium tests will need to be rewritten. I mean if everything is the same, could protractor tests fail because of angular version

Comment: Look into page object model. Writing tests using page objects will help insulate your tests from changes.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from V1.5 to V1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-5-to-1-6) it explains the breaking changes that will impact tests.

Comment: For unit script, I think you need to do some modify due to api changes on different angularjs version; For e2e script, you no need to rewrite them, but maybe need to upgrade protractor version, if so pay attention to break changes of new protractor, most protractor old api also work on new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS V1.6 release comes with a longer-than-usual list of breaking changes.

To give you a heads-up, here is a brief summary of the breaking changes that are expected to have the highest impact. Make sure you look them up in the full list below or check out the corresponding commits for more info.

- $location now uses '!' as the default hash-prefix for hash-bang URLs, instead of the empty string.
- $compile will (by default) not pre-assign bindings on component/directive controller instances.
- http imposes additional restrictions to JSONP requests for security reasons
- The improved support for input[type=range] means that the behaviour of range inputs (when bound to ngModel) has changed.
- ngTransclude now treats whitespace-only transclusion content as empty and uses the fallback content instead.
- ngAria/ngModel no longer overrides the default $inEmpty() method for custom checkbox-shaped controls.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from V1.5 to V1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-5-to-1-6)